# When was SQLite database file created?

Tags: c#, sqlite, uwp

I run the following code to test Sqlite but it seems the database file isn't created. When is it supposed to be created? I thought the file was to be created in the current directory (debug in my case) but I can't find it anywhere in the solution.

My code:

```
using (SqliteConnection db = new SqliteConnection("Filename=sqliteSample.db"))
{
    db.Open();
    var tableCommand = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS MyTable (Primary_Key INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, Text_Entry NVARCHAR(2048) NULL)";
    var createTable = new SqliteCommand(tableCommand, db);
    try
    {
        createTable.ExecuteReader();
        db.Close();
    }
    catch (SqliteException e)
    {
        //Do nothing
    }
}
```

Comment: What SQLite wrapper are you using?

Comment: The current directory might be the project directory. Make sure its not being created someplace else. The db.Open() won't create the database, but executing the command will. Since you didn't mention any exceptions, it created it someplace, you just have to find it.

Comment: @JoelLucsy: SQLite creates the database (by default, if it doesn't exist) when the connection is opened.

Comment: @MarkBenningfield SQLite creates the database file when it *actually* needs to write to the file for the first time. This allows changing parameters like the page size.

Comment: Why `ExecuteReader`, when you don't want a reader?

Comment: @CL. This is test code. It is not the application, just copied/pasted it. But thanks.

Comment: Just found the database here : C:\Users\MY_NAME\AppData\Local\Packages\f398a499-0092-462e-9b50-aab3651b4b69_kxamnsbhqvv2e\LocalState. Thought it would be created in the current folder of the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I switched my solution to one using Entity Framework so I'm not sure if the answer would be different. The db file is created when I call EnsureCreated.

```
public Contexte()
        {
            if (!_created)
            {
                _created = true;
                Database.EnsureDeleted();
                Database.EnsureCreated();
            }
        }
        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionbuilder)
        {
            optionbuilder.UseSqlite(@"Data Source=AideProf.db");
        }
```

The location of the file is C:\Users\MY_NAME\AppData\Local\Packages\package_id\LocalStat‌​e.